# How to update a Char list while maintaining rest of list (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I need to update a Char list (it's actually a list of Char lists, but for simplicity assume it's just a Char list). I have written an 'nth' function that gets the nth element from a list, but I need to be able to update that element and return the new list with the updated value.

I've done some researching, but the only methods I've found can return all elements up to the element to be updated, and I haven't been able to understand them enough to modify their behaviour. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Show the code, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the `i`'th position of a list, concatenate the first `i` elements, the element that you want to insert, and the last `length l - i - 1` elements. The `splitAt` function makes this very easy.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I ended up doing just after I posted the question :)